# Por que jsf não está reconhecendo listener no Bean?

Tags: java, java-ee, jsf, rich-faces

Por que a jsf não está reconhecendo o listener do Bean?

Meu bean:

```
/**
 * Listener que escuta a mudança do tipo de Solicitante
 * 
 * @param event
 */
public void mudarSolicitante(ValueChangeEvent event){
    logger.info("Novo objeto : " + event.getNewValue());
    solicitanteId = (Integer) event.getNewValue();
}
```

Eu chamo este listener do selectOneMenu, conforme abaixo:

```
<h:column>
<h:selectOneMenu
    value="#{atividadeController.solicitanteId }"
    id="solicitante">
    <f:selectItems 
         value="#{atividadeController.listaSelectSolicitantesAtivos}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" 
          actionListener="#{atividadeController.mudarSolicitante()}"
          ajaxSingle="true" immediate="true"></a4j:support>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Ao executar está sendo exibida a seguinte excecão:

```
javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /atividade/formAtividade.jsp(171,18) '#{atividadeController.mudarSolicitante()}' Method not found: com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.controller.AtividadeController@75b3883f.mudarSolicitante()
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:118)
```

Ou seja, está retornando que o método não existe no Bean.

Comment: Chegou a tentar sem os `()`? Quando você usa `actionListener="#{atividadeController.mudarSolicitante()}"` significa explicitamente um método sem parâmetros. Como você precisa do evento, então recomendo declarar o method expression somente pelo nome `actionListener="#{atividadeController.mudarSolicitante}"`.

Comment: Em vez de "<a4j:support " já tentou usar "<p:ajax" ?

Comment: Fiz a alteração retirando o `()` mas o erro permanece.....

Comment: `org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodNotFoundException: /atividade/formAtividade.jsp(171,18) '#{atividadeController.mudarSolicitante}' Method not found: com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.controller.AtividadeController@3f515f14.mudarSolicitante(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)'

Comment: Jose estou usando jsf 1.2 richfaces 3.3.3 (restrição do cliente)

Answer (score 0):

a tag a4j:support não tem um atributo valueChangeListener? Se tiver, é ele que você deve usar.

Comment: Já tentei, mas também não rolou.

Answer (score 0):

Salve jovem, também trabalho com essa sofrencia do JSF 1.2, quando preciso fazer algum evento com um selecOneMenu, faço um onchange="submit()" no próprio componente, segue exemplo:

```
<h:selectOneMenu styleClass="PaginaList" id="acordoListBox" value="#{pc_DadosPreEmpenhoPageForm.dadosPreEmpenhoDTO.acordo}" onchange="submit();" disabled="#{pc_DadosPreEmpenhoPageForm.tipoPreEmpenho eq 'Reserva'}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{pc_DadosPreEmpenhoPageForm.acordos}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Tenho um exemplo aqui no sistema com o a4j, ao invés de usar `ValueChangeEvent` usa o `ActionEvent`, segue exemplo:

```
public void alterarRecursoDoBID(ActionEvent event) {
        if (p.getModalidade().toUpperCase().contains("BID")) {
            p.setRecursoBID(true);
        } else {
            p.setRecursoBID(false);
        }
    }
```

Pagina:

```
<h:selectOneMenu styleClass="PaginaList" id="modalidadeListBox" disabled="#{pc_MeuBeanPageForm.processoRecebidoRender == true?false:true}" value="#{pc_MeuBeanPageForm.MeuBean.modalidade}" >
    <a4j:support event="onchange" ajaxSingle="true" actionListener="#{pc_MeuBeanPageForm.alterarRecursoDoBID}" reRender="recursoBIDRadio"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{pc_MeuBeanPageForm.modalidadeItens}" />
        <f:selectItem id="modalidadeInativo" itemValue="#{pc_MeuBeanPageForm.MeuBean.modalidade}" itemLabel="#{pc_MeuBeanPageForm.processoLicitatorio.modalidade}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```